# Why doesn't my NSView delegate method gets called?

Tags: macos, cocoa, delegates, nsview

I'm working on my first Mac app and I'm having some trouble with getting my NSView and it's delegate methods to work. I have a NSViewController that should response to mouse events, i.e mouseDown. This didn't work, instead I created a custom NSView subclass that looks like this:

```
// Delegate method
@protocol CanvasViewDelegate
    - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;
@end

@interface CanvasView : NSView
{
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;
@end

@implementation CanvasView
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [delegate mouseDown:event];
}
```

The NSViewController relevant parts that should act as the NSView's delegate looks like this:

```
#import "CanvasView.h"

@interface PaintViewController : NSViewController <CanvasViewDelegate>
{
    CanvasView *canvasView;
}

@property (strong) IBOutlet CanvasView *canvasView;

@end 

@synthesize canvasView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        canvasView = [[CanvasView alloc] init];
        canvasView.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Down");
}
```

Now, the method mouseDown doesn't get called, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just alloced and inited your view, but how do you actually make your view appear? Wouldn’t you want an IBOutlet to the CanvasView and then connect it via Interface Builder? Or, if you want to create it programmatically, wouldn’t you have to use initWithFrame: instead of just init, and then actually put the view someplace?

Comment: @Enchilada I have created the view with IB as part of a NSViewController.xib and assigned CanvasView as it's class. I add the viewConrollers view to the window in my app delegate like this: `// Insert code here to initialize your application
    viewController = [[PaintViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PaintViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[_window contentView] addSubview:viewController.view];` Is it here I should set the delegate? In that case, how? :)

Comment: Aren’t you missing a [self setView:canvasView] in your post’s code? Otherwise, how does the view controller know what its view is? Well, or you could do addSubview:viewController.canvasView in the code you just pasted in your above comment.

Comment: Hmm, don't think that helped. The delegate methods still doesn't get called. I'm going to try to create the view programatically instead and see if that helps.

Comment: If you haven’t already, try adding a drawRect method that fills the view with, say, a red color. Then you can at least see whether your view is getting displayed in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have tried that and it displays the view as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the view programmatically instead did work. Like this:

```
NSRect canvasRect = self.view.frame;
canvasView = [[CanvasView alloc] initWithFrame:canvasRect];
[self.view addSubview:canvasView];
canvasView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want an `NSView` subclass to accept events, you will have to implement:

```
 - (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
     return YES;
 }
```

as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW14).

Comment: Hi, the events seems to work inside the NSView alone. For example,  `- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Dragging");
}
` Inside the NSView get called, but not not if I make it a delegate method the way I described.

Comment: So you want to have the `NSViewController` handle the events? You'll need to call `setNextResponder:` on the pass the events to the controller. Your delegation pattern isn't really the right thing to be doing here. Have a look at the Cocoa Event-Handling Guide, particularly the section on the responder chain: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2